Execute failed in rviz, displaying error controller XXX failed with errOr PATH TOLERANCE VIOLATE
background
Implement joint simulation of rviz and gazebo
Problem description:
In rviz, it is possible to plan and execute failures, displaying the error 'controller XXX failed with errOr PATH TOLERANCE VIOLATD'. The robotic arm stops running for a period of time and cannot reach the target position.
Error: controller's scaled pos joint trajcontroller 'failed with errOr PATH TOLERANCE VIOLATE: shoulder lift joint patherror -0.101387
Specific details and context:
Suspected to be a problem with the controller, the error message shows a scaled pos joint trajcontroller error.
After adjusting the controller, it was found that there were 2 files.
The controller scaled pos joint trajcontroller is located under Moveit's config.
The other controller in Gazebo's config file has many controllers, but it is unclear what they are related to the scaled pos joint trajcntroller.
Attempted solutions:
Attempt to modify the stopped-velocity_tolerance parameter value to 0;
Modify the goal in the control file:
shoulder_pan_joint: {trajectory: 0.1, goal: 0.0}
shoulder_lift_joint: {trajectory: 0.1, goal: 0.0}
elbow_joint: {trajectory: 0.1, goal: 0.0}
wrist_1_joint: {trajectory: 0.1, goal: 0.0}
wrist_2_joint: {trajectory: 0.1, goal: 0.0}
wrist_3_joint: {trajectory: 0.1, goal: 0.0
